# Is there a verb for "driving" a horse?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for the action of telling the horse you are on to move forward, turn left, turn right, or the like?

I assume "driving" would be the easiest to understand, but it sounds like it does not fit a living thing like a horse.

The word "controlling" seems most accurate, yet controlling an animal gives negative connotations, does it not?

Comment: You ***ride*** a horse.

Comment: You'll probably see negative connotations as well with "command a horse," but that's what one does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can *turn* a horse, *stop a horse*, *check* a horse (slow down or stop it), *spur* a horse (tell it to go faster). But if you want the verb that corresponds to *drive a car*, it's *ride a horse*.

This is similar to a motorcycle; you can *steer, turn, accelerate,* or *brake* a motorcycle, but the verb that encompasses all of these is *ride*.

Comment: You can also _operate_ a car or a motorcycle, although I do not think one would operate a horse.

Answer (score 2):

You can [*steer* a horse](http://animals.mom.me/steer-horse-reins-3105.html). Although this might not cover the full range of commands. But it does cover turning and the like. Possibly also covers moving forward (see link.)

Answer (score 2):

*Driving,* in relation to horses, is the managing (from behind) of such horses as are pulling a plow, sled, or wheeled vehicle.

I would suggest that besides *ride* you consider the verb *manage:*

> To control (a person or animal); to exert one's authority or rule over. [OED]

This is the more suitable for equestrian application in that the noun *manage* once meant

> The training, handling, and directing of a horse. With *the:* the art of training and managing horses. [OED]

Thus Hotspur’s wife (in Shakespeare’s *Henry IV Pt. 1* 2.4) complains that in dreams her husband is wont to

> Speake tearmes of mannage to thy bounding steed.

Answer (score 2):

One *rides* a horse and *steers* with the reins.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not a single verb that covers the action of "driving" a horse. I've found several entries in [Macmillan Dictionary Online](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/horse-riding).
Maybe this link can help as a kickstarter for further research.

Comment: As @Peter Shor points out - you ***ride*** a horse. This involves having copious *riding lessons* ideally as a child. ***Learning to ride*** involves how to stop, start, steer, get on and off, what to do if you fall off, learning to jump, care for the horse, do dressage etc. It is all part of the skill of horsemanship. But it is called ***riding***. What do you do at week-ends? *I ride*. And when you use the single word on its own it doesn't imply a bicycle or motor-bike. It means you ride a horse.

Comment: It seems *ride* is too broad for OP's purposes. OP seems to be looking for a more specific term.

Answer (score 0):

You indeed "ride" a horse, i.e. sit on them and control their movement, but when it comes to urging a horse to move in a specified direction, you "[**drive**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/drive)" them.

> drive: [with object and adverbial of direction] Urge or force (animals or people) to move in a specified direction ([**OED**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drive))
>
> *Jessie lowered her head and drove the horse uphill [urged the horse to move uphill], ignoring the wet branches that whipped and stung her legs.* ([**Lone Star 25**](https://books.google.fr/books?id=U0aXATgRhv0C&pg=PT51&dq=%22drove+the+horse%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCGoVChMIw7Ta4K65yAIVQ9IaCh1zlQ_B#v=onepage&q=%22drove%20the%20horse%22&f=false))

Alternately, you can also [**guide**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drove+the+horse%2Cguided+the+horse&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrove%20the%20horse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cguided%20the%20horse%3B%2Cc0) a horse.

> guide: to direct or control the path or course of (something) ([**M-W**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guide))
>
> *He adjusted his hat and guided the horse uphill through a stand of yellow pine.* ([**Common Threads**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=lwXFvrAv6m8C&pg=PA55&dq=%22guided+the+horse+uphill%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIjMahtLa5yAIVRj8aCh0GcwKj#v=onepage&q=%22guided%20the%20horse%20uphill%22&f=false))

Comment: I have never heard anybody use the word *drive* applied to an animal they were sitting on (as opposed to one that was pulling a cart they're in, for which the word is quite unexceptional). And I'm not convinced that the one citation you found for this really means anything.